# JMeter Append Random Number to Form Field

Tags: jmeter

I am load testing a registration form on my internal website and it has one field which must be unique (email address). I'm using JMeter (following [this tutorial](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)). I have a HTTP Request under the Recording Controller in a Thread Group in my test plan.

How do I configure this HTTP Request to add a random number to my email address field (see screenshot)? My company's internal test email server will accept anything at its domain (so like testing347387438@my-internal-test-email-server.com). How can I configure JMeter to add a random number to the email address which should make it unique?
[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [random function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random).

So your email address will be like:

```
testing${__Random(1,10000000)}@my-internal-test-email-server.com
```

Answer (score 13):

Also you can use **${__UUID}@test-email.com** - it ensures that your email will be unique. Always.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is already answered but following can be useful to someone.

We can use "Config Element -> Random Variable" as well. This variable can be re-used in full jmeter scope and be used for assertion test against responses.

Process is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]