# JMeter - how to simulate an email address AND a confirm email address

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to setup a JMeter test plan and need to create unique email addresses for submission.  I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13272906/203141) that suggested using the [Random Function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random).

The problem is that I need to generate an email address AND reference that same created email in the confirm_email field.  I need to randomly generate an email address and then use it twice.  How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I learned that there's an extra parameter to the __Random function that can hold a variable name that you can reference later.

So, my Parameters are:

```
email : ${__Random(1,10000000,refName)}@jmeter.com
email 2 : ${refName}@jmeter.com
```

Voila!